# Factorization of multivariate polynomials

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, factoring, multivariate-polynomial

I am trying to factor a polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$ of degree 4 in 4 indeterminates, but I realized I don't know any algorithm to do so and no software to help me.

Is there an algorithm to factor this kind of polynomials? Is it possible to know at least if they are irreducible? I'd be thankful for any answer or reference you can provide and any software you can recommend.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The newest versions of PARI/GP can factor multivariate polynomials over $\mathbb Q$ , but the running time increases fast with the number of variables.

Comment: There are criteria for irreducibiliy (have a look at this site). Do you have an explicit example, which we could test?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, when you say have a look at this site I don't see any link (or do you mean math se?). The coefficients of my polynomial depends on some parameters but an example coud be $4u^4 -24u^2v^2 + 4v^4 -8u^2w^2 + 8v^2w^2 + 4w^4 + 8u^2s^2-8v^2s^2 -8w^2s^2 + 4s^4$. I know this should be the square of a polynomyal of degree 2 but I couldn't factor it.

Comment: It works fine with any CAS I test: the result is  $$4(s^2 + u^2 + 2uv - v^2 - w^2)(s^2 + u^2 - 2uv - v^2 - w^2)$$